# клавиатура перекрывает EditText, а должна поднимать его на собой

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, android-softkeyboard

- android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" - пробовал.
- android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" - пробовал.
- android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" - пробовал.
- android:fitsSystemWindows="true" для корневого ConstraintLayout - пробовал.
- заменить NestedScroolView на ScroolView - пробовал.
- getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE); - пробовал.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
разметка:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="mainViewModel"
            type="com.checkphone.screens.main.MainViewModel" />

    </data>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        tools:context=".screens.main.MainActivity">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/main_back">

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="252dp"
                android:background="@drawable/main_gradient"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:text="@string/app_name"
                android:textColor="@color/main_tittle"
                android:textSize="32sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/cardView"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/view"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/view"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/view" />

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cardView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="16dp"
                app:cardElevation="4dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/view"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/view"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/main_logo"
                        android:layout_width="126dp"
                        android:layout_height="126dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                        app:imageSrc="@{mainViewModel.logo}"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <ProgressBar
                        android:id="@+id/main_spinner"
                        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:visibility="@{mainViewModel.progress}"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/main_logo"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/main_logo"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/main_logo"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/main_logo" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/main_tv_operator"
                        style="@style/main_tv_dataphone"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                        android:text="@{mainViewModel.tvOperator}"
                        android:textSize="24sp"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/main_logo"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/main_logo"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/main_logo" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView3"
                        style="@style/main_tv_dataphone_hint"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                        android:text="@string/main_tv_operator"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/main_tv_operator"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/main_tv_operator"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/main_tv_operator" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/main_tv_phone"
                        style="@style/main_tv_dataphone"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                        android:text="@{mainViewModel.tvPhone}"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/main_tv_operator"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/main_tv_operator"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView5"
                        style="@style/main_tv_dataphone_hint"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
                        android:text="@string/main_tv_phone"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/main_tv_phone"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/main_tv_phone"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/main_tv_phone"
                        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:text="@string/main_tv_user_hint"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/main_tv_user_hint"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/main_ed_phone"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cardView" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/main_ed_phone"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/main_ed_hint"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:text="@={mainViewModel.edPhone}"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/main_btn_check"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/main_btn_check"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
                android:text="@string/main_btn_check"
                android:enabled="@{mainViewModel.btnCheckEnabled}"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />


        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</layout>
```

Comment: Может кому пригодится: я использовал вот эту библиотеку (https://github.com/laobie/StatusBarUtil) - чтоб сделать прозрачный стаусБар и именно в этом и была проблема. Как только убрал код - который прозрачнит статусБар - все заработало, при появлении клавиатуры - EditText поднимается вместе сней

Comment: Прзрачный статус бар: в стилях, в параметры темы добавить: <item name="android:statusBarColor">#00000000</item>
        <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>, работает с версии API21